# Which Drupal 8.1.x Rest API property in the JSON request controls Drupal's File status (Temporary and Permanent) logic?

Tags: json, rest, drupal-8, permanent, drupal-files

Which Drupal Rest API property in the JSON request controls Drupal's File status (Temporary and Permanent) logic?

I am trying to upload via **Multipart/form-data** (i.e. JSON data plus attached [uploaded] file) to Drupal 8.1.x CMS. So far, the upload is successful. However, In Drupal uploaded files (via REST) are initially stored by default with "TEMPORARY" status.

I want to tell Drupal to set the status of the file to "PERMANENT" when it stores my file into the Drupal CMS. I did some searching and found out that the keyword "status" in File.php did the magic around TEMPORARY and PERMANENT. So far, I have been including the property "status" in my Json request but Drupal generates an Internal error --> message:

```
"Access denied on creating field 'status'"
```

after having set 
    "status": [{"value": "1"}]

**BTW:** I have tried different variations on the value representation of "value", that is "1", 1, true, "true", ..., since I was not able to get more information about the API specification specific to the Rest File upload interface.

I have searched Drupal site for a solution but with no satisfying results yet.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to construct the JSON request with status PERMANENT?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug, which can be fixed in the following Drupal source file:

```
diff --git a/src/Normalizer/FileEntityNormalizer.php b/src/Normalizer/FileEntityNormalizer.php
index cdb1df0..3237905 100644
--- a/src/Normalizer/FileEntityNormalizer.php
+++ b/src/Normalizer/FileEntityNormalizer.php
@@ -52,6 +52,7 @@ class FileEntityNormalizer extends ContentEntityNormalizer {
     else {
       throw new \RuntimeException(SafeMarkup::format('Failed to write @filename.', array('@filename' => $entity->getFilename())));
     }
+    $entity->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
     return $entity;
   }
 }
```

**References**

- [Files created with REST API are only temporary [#2756127] | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2756127)
- [MIME type not set when file uploaded with REST API [#2754775] | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2754775)
- [File Entity (fieldable files) | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)
- [How to upload image using REST resources for File resource '/entity/file/{file}'? [#2682341] | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2682341)

Comment: This might also helpful 
https://www.solutionspirit.com/how-to-post-or-upload-files-by-json-rest-api-in-drupal-8-x-site/